# My ASP.NET MVC application is Anemic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I read Fowlers description of Anemic Domain and I believe I have those symptoms. I have several objects doing nothing but passing data around in different packages. I also have several Services that pretty much handle all the behavior (executive functioning). I am starting to lose track of why and what i did and where to find certain tasks.

The application does what I want, but i wonder if i just have a procedural program in oo disguise. Perhaps I can never shake my procedural programming past? should I?

In MVC, Should I eliminate my services and spread that responsibility to my Controllers and Model Objects?

I appreciate analogies between MVC concepts and DDD conepts...

Answer (score 3):

I think controllers should be relatively thin. Their job is mainly being taking the request, delegating it to the appropriate application services and determining the correct action result.

If you're feeling that your domain entities are overly anemic I would suggest going over your Services and determine whether that functionality belongs on an Entity instead. I found this was my biggest problem starting with DDD was that I would push all behavior to Services rather than critically thinking about whether this was something more appropriate on the Entity.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the Evans book as suggested in one of your previous questions?